# venue menu update api

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm trying to figure out the way to update menu of a venue through Foursquare API (Merchant Platform, as I understand). I've found how to GET info of the menu, but there is no POST request specified to update the menu.

Am I missing something, or is this just not implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare gets their menu data from menu providers, such as [locu](https://locu.com/). Merchants can upload their menu information to one of these providers for free, and it will show up on Foursquare (among other places).